# Project Euler Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on the Project Euler problems. I am on [Problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) and for some reason I am getting the wrong answer for it. I don't know if its my math logic that's the problem or if the logic for the code is wrong. Here's the code:

```
def getSumMult3_5(n):
    count = 0
    i = 0
    i_1 = 0
    while i*5 < n:
        count += i*5
        i += 1
    while i_1*3 < n:
        count += i_1*3
        i_1 += 1
    return count

print getSumMult3_5(1000)
```

It's returning that

```py
count = 266333
```

but that is not the correct answer. Count should equal 233168. Can anybody help me figure out why it's doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're double counting numbers that are multiples of both 5 and 3, such as 15.

Comment: Oh wow I'm stupid. I didn't read the question carefully. It's multiples of 3 OR 5! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You are double counting multiples of 15. You can solve this by introducing a third while statement to decrease the count by 1 for each multiple of 15.

I suggest using an if/else statement:

```py
def getSumMult3_5(n):
  s = 0
  for i in range(1, n+1):
    if i%3==0:
      s+=i
    elif i%5==0:
      s+=i
  return s

print getSumMult3_5(1000)
```

This is because that *if* the number is a multiple of 3, it does not check whether it is a multiple of 5; if it is *not* a multiple of 3, it checks whether it is a multiple of 5.

I also recommend using *s* as a variable name because it represents sum, which can't be used as it is a keyword. *Count* seems to refer to the number of times something occurs.

By only using one variable, and using an if/else statement, execution time will be less and it will be less confusing to read.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code:

```
running_sum = 0





for i in range(1,1000):
    if i % 3 == 0:
      running_sum+=(i) 
      
    elif i % 5 == 0:
      running_sum+=(i)
print running_sum
```

You're double-counting numbers like 15 that are multiples of both